# Grails Intellij resource.groovy errors

Tags: spring, grails, intellij-idea, config

I just decided to give a go to Grails and since I use mostly Intellij for Java stuff, I dont want to use GTS, so everything works fine so far with a few small glitches on getting grails working smooth on Intellij 12, but my bean names are highlighted as errors in the resources.groovy file. They all work and its fine, but its just tedious to see the file marked with errors. Do you know if there is a way around that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known bug:

- [IDEA-88816](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88816) IDEA fails to parse Spring DSL in resources.groovy